# How to fix try/catch Java NullPointerException

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception, bufferedimage

I am trying to create a 2D platform game, by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJSII25WrAz5Pf1QMx0aUL0pEuZzdFp7W) tutorial. I have created an `Images()`-class which looks like this:
package Resources;

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Images {

    public static BufferedImage[] tileBlocks;

    public Images(){
        tileBlocks = new BufferedImage[1];
        try{
            tileBlocks[0] = ImageIO.read(
                    // TODO: Fix the error caused by this try/catch
                    (Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResourceAsStream("TileBlocks/block_brick.png")))
            );
        } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

And I created an instantation of it in my `GamePanel()`-class, which looks like this

```
package Main;

import GameState.GameStateManager;
import Resources.Images;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.Serial;

@SuppressWarnings("BusyWait")
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Game thread
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    int FPS = 60;                                       // Frames per second
    long targetTime = 1000 / FPS;                       // Set target time

    // Set the dimension of the game-window
    public static final int WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 600;

    private GameStateManager gsm = new GameStateManager(); // Game state manager object

    public GamePanel(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);

        // TODO: Fix error (Reports instantiation of utility classes using the new keyword)
        new Images();

        start();
    }

    // Start the game (initialize)
    private void start() {
        isRunning = true;
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);            // Referring to Runnable
        thread.start();                              // Call to our game-loop
    }

    // Game-loop
    public void run() {

        long start, elapsed, wait;                          // Keep track of time
        gsm = new GameStateManager();                       // Initialize game state manager

        while (isRunning) {
            start = System.nanoTime(); // Start timer
            update();                  // Update the game-logic
            repaint();                 // Re-paint the board (built-in method from java.awt)
            elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;

            // If everything runs in under the target time we wait (so it runs equally in all computers)
            wait = targetTime - elapsed / 1000000;  // Divide by 1 000 000 to get milli-seconds
            if (wait <= 0) { wait = 5; }  // Keep wait a positive value

            try {
                Thread.sleep(wait);
            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
        }
    }

    // Updating all game-logic
    public void update() { gsm.update(); }// Call methods from game state manager in the game panel class

    // Where we draw the graphics
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);         // Built-in method from java.awt
        g.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);   // Clear the screen before drawing
        gsm.draw(g);                     // Call method from game state manager in the game panel class
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        gsm.keyPressed(e.getKeyCode());  // getKeyCode() turns KeyEvent into an integer
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        gsm.keyReleased(e.getKeyCode()); // getKeyCode() turns KeyEvent into an integer
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }
}
```

I get an error saying

```
Instantiation of utility class 'Images' 
Inspection info: Reports instantiation of utility classes using the new keyword.
In utility classes, all fields and methods are static. 
Instantiation of such classes is most likely unnecessary and indicates a mistake.
```

And when I try to run the game it doesn't launch, I only get a `NullPointerException`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208)
    at inf112.skeleton.app/Resources.Images.<init>(Images.java:17)
    at inf112.skeleton.app/Main.GamePanel.<init>(GamePanel.java:35)
    at inf112.skeleton.app/Main.Game.game(Game.java:10)
    at inf112.skeleton.app/Main.Game.main(Game.java:20)
```

But if I remove the the instantation, the game launches, but then it crashes with even more errors

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Cannot load from object array because "Resources.Images.tileBlocks" is null
etc...
```

If I remove the `Objects.requireNonNull` from
`tileBlocks[0] = ImageIO.read((getClass().getResourceAsStream("TileBlocks/block_brick.png"))`

The game launches, but it crashes and I get another error saying

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Cannot load from object array because "Resources.Images.tileBlocks" is null
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why is my list of `tileBlocks null`? How can I read the image and display it on the `tileBlocks`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You should essentially never catch a `NullPointerException` specifically: it's an indication of a programming error, and you should fix that rather than attempting to recover from it at runtime.

Comment: NPE is probably because the resource "TileBlocks/block_brick.png" isn't there. You try to read it, it does not exist, and null is returned. Hence the NPE. Check first if you have that image, if it is accessible, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put file "block_brick.png" in directory "TileBlocks" in classpath.

Comment: I have two source folders:  `src` and `Resources`. Inside the `Resources` directory, I have a folder called `TileBlocks` where the png-file is stored. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I added a forward-slash in the file-path, I changed `TileBlocks/block_brick.png` to `/TileBlocks/block_brick.png`  and now it works! Thank you!